# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Так было(,) и так будет" — нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я согласен, тут нет сложносочиненной структуры в явном виде.
Но самое, имхо, правильное, передавать крылатое выражение в исходном виде. ***"Так было, так будет!"***
Это ставшие известными слова Шефа жандармов А. А. Макарова по поводу ленских событий 1912 г. Подробности [тут](http://bibliotekar.ru/encSlov/18/6.htm)

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, запятая не нужна. Это предложение сложносочиненное, части которого представляют собой односоставные безличные предложения.